# Query nested elements from unknown number of arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Querying to get an element from an array that is nested in an object is not a big deal. But, when you have a self-repeating structure that is nested within itself, it seems to become much more complicated. Here is an example document:

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "Alpha",
    "options": [
        {
            "_id": "2",
            "name": "Bravo",
            "options": [
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "3",
            "name": "Charlie",
            "options": [
                {
                    "_id": "4",
                    "name": "Delta",
                    "options": [
                        ...etc
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, here we have a number of arrays holding objects that are alike. This is useful for, say, a tabbed interface being configured out of a DB.

What I'm looking to do is actually be able to modify the documents that are further down in the structure **without knowing their positions in the ancestor arrays**. So far I've only found the "$" update operator helpful when you don't have to deal with more than one level of arrays. But as you can see, there are arrays within objects that are inside of arrays here, so it becomes complicated.

Pushing to an array in the first level is not difficult:

```
db.myCollection.update({_id: "1", "options._id": "2"}, {$push: {"options.$.options": {...object definition here...}}});
```

This works. However, when you try to go deeper into the structure, I don't understand how to target the deeper portions of the document.

The following query is not working for me, and I'm hoping somebody could help me out:

```
db.myCollection.update({_id: "1", "options.options._id": "4"}, {"options.options.$.options": {...object definition here...}});
```

It whines about how I can't use dot syntax. Which makes sense, because in this case "options.options" is ambiguous. I was hoping that the query selection would have pointed to the right place.

tl;dr: How do you update document portions that are multiple levels deep nested within more than one array where you do not know the index of the target element? You can select it, so you should be able to modify it.

Comment: Don't "nest" arrays. The [positional `$`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator cannot handle it and can only ever match the "first" index found, and that allways means the "outer" array only. Work within the contraints and "flatten" your schema to have "at most" **one** level of arrays only.

Comment: @blakesseven The alternate approach is storing every entry individually and linking them via a parent id. This represents a query nightmare when i want to retrieve the entire document laid out above. Can you suggest another pattern or a simplified way to select multiple chained ancestors in a manageable way?

Comment: @dudewad, what did you end up doing? I'm faced with the same issue.

Comment: @GabrielFair I deemed that architecturally Mongo doesn't really support this use case in a sane manner. It ended up creating some pretty nasty code, at the least. As for the final solution, I think we ended up changing architecture to support the new requirements. Its been so long now (I've changed companies) that I can't actually remember the final concrete solution... sorry :/

Comment: (And FWIW, nobody on our cloud team knew how to do this in a good way either, and these were former and now current google folks, so they at least kinda know what they're talking about).

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. I might do the same and switch to postgres and normalize things